# search external file by first letter of word and update vars if exist

Tags: php, regex

I want to us `str_replace` to search through a short `.txt` file for 2 words that start with 2 specific different characters; ie. `s` and `b` - I may use to replace contents of my post variables with the 2 found words.

```
    $starID = //  I would like to update with found word in external file starting with 's' if exists.
    $MAG = // I would like to update with found word in external file starting with 'b' if exists.

    $pageBody = file_get_contents('./data.txt');

    $newMessage = str_replace("$starID", "$MAG", $pageBody);
```

---

```
<div class="display"><?php echo ($newMessage) ?></div>
```

Comment: Your description is extremely vague, you should add in sample text and what you're trying to match there

Comment: also, `php` short code for echo'ing out a variable might be handy for you here `<?=$var;?>`

Comment: Definitely sounds like a regex situation. However i'm unsure exactly what you're searching for? Is $startID and $MAG supposed to be the two words you need to find and replace? Or the start characters of the two words you need to replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work to make the two replacements.

```
$starID = $_POST['starID'];
$MAG = $_POST['MAG'];

$pageBody = file_get_contents('./data.txt');

$replaceMsg = preg_replace(/s[^\s]*/, $starID, $pageBody);
$newMessage = preg_replace(/b[^\s]*/, $MAG, $replaceMsg);
```

This uses preg_replace (rather than str_replace that you requested) along with a regex to match any word starting with s and until the first space. (And then the same for b afterwards)

Notice: This only replaces the first match. If there are potentially multiple words with s/d you want replaced, you're going to have to make the regex global, by adding a 'g' at the end like this:

```
/s[^\s]*/g
```